# How to pass change the toggle button through indexpath of tableview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tableview where I am displaying my values from database in tableview cells. In this tableview cellforrowatindexpath, I have created a button with an image on it and set selector for it. So when I click on the button my selector is called and it changes my image to another image.

But the problem is it does not identifies the indexpath i.e. if 4 rows are present in the tableview and if I click on the first row button, its image should change but problem is 4th row action is performed and its image is changed because it does not get the proper indexpath of the image to change.

This is my cellforrowatindexpath code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    appDelegate = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TAlarmCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 20, 20, 20);   
        mimageButton.tag = 1;
        onButtonView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 50)];
        onButtonView.tag = 2;
        onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
        [mimageButton setImage:onButtonView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];

        [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType::) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


}




     return cell;

}
```

This is my changemapType code

```
-(void)changeMapType:(NSIndexPath*)path1:(UIButton*)sender{
appDelegate.changeimagetype =!appDelegate.changeimagetype;
if(appDelegate.changeimagetype == YES)
{
    onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"];
    [mimageButton setImage:onButtonView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    appDelegate.changeimagetype = YES;
}
else
{
    onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
    [mimageButton setImage:onButtonView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    appDelegate.changeimagetype = NO;

}


}
```

Comment: mimageButton.tag set this tag value according to your cellidentfier. and no need to send any thing as a argument in selector

Comment: you are doing entirely wrong thing

Comment: @Ron could u please exp me in detail

Comment: @Rani you have multiple sections or not?

Comment: @Narayana i dont have multiple sections

Answer (score 1):

Don't break table view cell reuse just to put a different tag on each button. If your cells are the same, use the same reuse identifier.

You can find out the index path of the sender like this, without any need to mess around with tags. It also works for multi section tables.

```
CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>I don't think you can have additional arguments in an `@selector` like that. What you might have to do is subclass UIButton and add an `NSIndexPath` property (or even just an `int`) and in `-(void)changeMapType:(MyCustomButton*)sender` access the property there.</s>

Also it seems you do not even use the index path in `changeMapType` so that will need to be changed as well.

**EDIT:** Is it the button image you are trying to change? In which case you don't need the index path at all, or a subclass. Just use `[sender setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourTableView` for getting the Index Path.. Try something like this.

```
  - (void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender {

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)button.superview;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### I think following code might help you..

---

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIView *myCheckbox = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIButton *myBt1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];

    if([appDelegate.changeimagetype == YES"]){
       [myBt1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];       
    }
    else {
       [myBt1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];       
    }
    [myBt1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btcheckbox:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [myBt1 setTag:indexPath.row];
    [myCheckbox addSubview:myBt1];

    [myBt1 release];
    [myCheckbox release];
    [cell addsubview:myview];
    return cell;    
}
```

---

```
-(void) btcheckbox:(id) sender
{
    UIButton *currentButton = (UIButton *) sender;

    if([[currentButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"]])
    {
         appDelegate.changeimagetype = YES;
         [currentButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else if([[currentButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"]])
    {
         appDelegate.changeimagetype = NO;
         [currentButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask me if you have any question,about above answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
                   NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row];
                appDelegate = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
                cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[[TAlarmCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

                   UIButton *mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 20, 20, 20);   
                    mimageButton.tag = indexPath.row;
                    //onButtonView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 50)];
                    //onButtonView.tag = 2;
                   // onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
                    [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    mimageButton.selected = NO;
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];

                    [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
          }
    return cell;
    }




-(void)changeMapType:(UIButton*)sender{

    if(sender.selected == YES)
    {
            // onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"];
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        sender.selected = NO;
    }
    else
    {
            //onButtonView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"];
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        sender.selected = YES;

    }

}
```

Comment: this code is not working.The problem is when if their are 3 rows in tableview and when i click on my first row tableview button then the image of the last row is getting changed.What may be the problem.Thanks